# Aggregate Populate array of ids with Their Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm Strugling with some aggregation functions in mongodb.
I want to get books Documents in author's document that has just books ids as array of strings ids like this :

Author Document

```
{
  "_id" : "10",
  "full_name" : "Joi Dark",
  "books" : ["100", "200", "351"],
}
```

And other documents (books) :

```
{
    "_id" : "100",
    "title" : "Node.js In Action",
    "ISBN" : "121215151515154",
    "date" : "2015-10-10"
}
```

So in result i want this :

```
{
  "_id" : "10",
  "full_name" : "Joi Dark",
  "books" : [
       {
           "_id" : "100",
           "title" : "Node.js In Action",
           "ISBN" : "121215151515154",
           "date" : "2015-10-10"
       },
       {
           "_id" : "200",
           "title" : "Book 2",
           "ISBN" : "1212151454515154",
           "date" : "2015-10-20"
       },
       {
           "_id" : "351",
           "title" : "Book 3",
           "ISBN" : "1212151454515154",
           "date" : "2015-11-20"
       }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which retrieves data from the nominated collection in `from` based on the matching of the `localField` to the `foreignField`:

```
db.authors.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "$books",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "localField": "books",
    "as": "books"
  }}
])
```

The `as` is where in the document to write an "array" containing the related documents. If you specify an existing property ( such as is done here ) then that property is overwritten with the new array content in output.

If you have a MongoDB before MongoDB 3.4 then you may need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array of `"books"` as the `localField` first:

```
db.authors.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$books" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "$books",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "localField": "books",
    "as": "books"
  }}
])
```

Which creates a new document for each array member in the original document, therefore use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) again and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to create the original form:

```
db.authors.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$books" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "$books",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "localField": "books",
    "as": "books"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$books" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "full_name": { "$first" "$full_name" },
    "books": { "$push": "$books" }
  }}
])
```

If in fact your `_id` values in the foreign collection of of `ObjectId` type, but you have values in the `localField` which are "string" versions of that, then you need to convert the data so the types match. There is no other way.

Run something like this through the shell to convert:

```
var ops = [];
db.authors.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc.books = doc.books.map( book => new ObjectId(book.valueOf()) );

  ops.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": {
        "$set": { "books": doc.books }
      }
    }
  });

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.authors.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.authors.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

That will convert all the values in the `"books"` array into real `ObjectId` values that can actually match in a `$lookup` operation.

Comment: it is not working, return empty array. books document has _id typed ObjectId, but in authors document i saved just ids as string.

Comment: @JahangirAhmad Well **you** need to fix that then. Your question shows "strings" in both fields. So fix your data to make the "object id like" strings actually into `ObjectId` values. Do you need assistance with that? Please update your question to show the real data. And by "update" I mean "in addition" and do not overwrite the data you placed in your original question. So I just rolled back your revision. Don't make changes to the context of questions you ask once you get an answer.

Comment: @JahangirAhmad You cannot match a string to an `ObjectId`. Do you need help understanding how to convert them? If you do then ask. Stop editing the question.

Comment: Yes please help me convert that

Comment: @JahangirAhmad Added a shell script for you to run a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on top of the previous answer. If your input consists of an array of strings and you want to convert them to ObjectIds, you can achieve this by using a [projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/), followed by a [map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and the [`$toObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) method.

```
db.authors.aggregate([
 { $project: {
      books: {
         $map: {
            input: '$books',
            as: 'book',
            in: { $toObjectId: '$$book' },
         },
      },
  },},
  { $lookup: {
       from: "$books",
       foreignField: "_id",
       localField: "books",
       as: "books"
     }
  },
])
```

Ideally, your database would be formatted in such a manner that your aggregates are stored as ObjectIds, but in the case where that is not an option, this poses as a viable solution.

Comment: Thanks. This worked in $reduce, too:

 {
        $addFields: {
          firstSectionPostIds: {
            $reduce: {
              input: '$firstSection.items',
              initialValue: [],
              in: { $concatArrays: ['$$value', [{ $toObjectId: '$$this.postId' }]] },
            },
          },
        },
      },